# Issue with sharing in twitter

Tags: twitter, windows-phone-7

I am about to implement a twitter sharing functionality in my WP7 app, but ... there is a really tricky issue. So, shortly explained my code is same like most popular WP7 twitter share examples(using OAuth): **SharingApp** - http://shelastyle.net/blog/sharing-to-facebook-twitter-and-email-in-windows-phone-7/ and **Twitt** - http://twitt.codeplex.com/ .

The issue I am experiencing is, that when I authenticate on the twitter auth page, instead of redirection to my app, I am getting "We are having trouble displaying this page" (and the NavigationFailed is fired). I am getting the same error if I try to turn back to my app from the authentication page. The code is basically same like in the examples above, the only difference is, that the examples use the non-Mango version. (Actually, I have noticed, that the twitter authentication page is different for Mango and non-Mango apps, which means, that twitter did some changes obviously)
I am attaching screenshots right before the error(I have highlighted the action, which triggers the error) and a screenshot with the error.

Screen 1:
[image]

Screen 2:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Every help and thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you listen to Navigating event? You should also make sure JS is enabled.   private static void WbNavigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(e.Uri.ToString());
        }

Comment: I am handling the Navigation_Failed event for debugging purposes and the Uri there seems logical and fine.(THe exception itself doesn't say anything tbh) I will continue digging into this, 10x for the efforts. ;-)

Comment: I'd handle the Navigating event for the WebBrowser, to see exactly what happens (perhaps the site keeps trying to navigate in a loop, or something). Also, what happens when you use the default IE app?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question directly, but if you only want the user to be able to post status updates to Twitter, you can use the ShareStatusTask instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharestatustask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to Share? If it is just web content, that you can link to, use the [ShareLinkTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.sharelinktask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) that was introduced in the Mango release. It will save you so much custom code.